# Magento - onepage checkout review coupon / discount colspan

Tags: magento, checkout, coupon, onestepcheckout

I am searching for the discount / coupon phtml file which is used for the onepage reviewstep. I have a wrong colspan. In this view I need a colspan 3 but from magento i get a colspan 1. 
How can I change this setting?

Greetings

Answer (score -1):

You can get the discount coupon phtml in 
"frontend\base\default\template\checkout/cart/coupon.phtml".
You can make changes to it but before that overide it to your theme.

Comment: Thanx for the reply. I ment the discount on the review step in the onepage checkout, where the discount is calculated.